# Vuetify: Data table slot value to toggle another slot value

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am using a Vuetify data table and I am using **v-slot:item** on two of the columns to insert [switches](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selection-controls/).

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="records"
  :search="search"
  :items-per-page="5"
>
  <template v-slot:item.monitor="{ item }">
    <v-switch v-model="item.monitor" color="success"></v-switch>
  </template>
  <template v-slot:item.manage="{ item }">
    <v-switch v-model="item.manage" color="success"></v-switch>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

What I want to do is set the switches like an **Item Group** so that only one may be selected (on) at a time, but both can be false (off). So only one can have a true value.

[image]

I have tried using the **[Item Group component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/item-groups/)** and [got that to work](https://codepen.io/MagRat/pen/MWKyOMN), but I am not sure if it is even possible within the table the way I want since these two switches are in separate slots. I am under the impression that the **v-item** should be sibling components, so that makes me think that would't work for this situation.

Comment: You won't be able to use `v-item-group` with table rows - the browser will ignore anything other than TD inside a TR tag and anything other than TR inside a TBODY tag. You have 2 options: (a) set the `v-model` of all switches on the same row to be an array and then use a watcher which will unshift values from those arrays if there are more than 1 element in the array; (b) set a `@change` handler on each switch and uncheck all the other switches on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there are two different approches to this problem. You can either:

- Watch the `records` array to detect changes in either `monitor` or `manage` attributes of one of its objects.
- Do not use `v-model` directive on the switches but provide a readonly value, then change it manually on click.

I prefer the second option. You can do it like so:

**Template section**

```html
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="records">
      <template v-slot:item.monitor="{ item }">
        <v-switch
          :input-value="item.monitor"
          readonly
          color="success"
          @click.stop="setSwitchesForItem(item.id, 'monitor', !item.monitor)"
        />
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.manage="{ item }">
        <v-switch
          :input-value="item.manage"
          readonly
          color="success"
          @click.stop="setSwitchesForItem(item.id, 'manage', !item.manage)"
        />
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

A couple of things to note here:

- `v-model` has been replaced by `:input-value`
- readonly props has been set
- the click event calls a custom method. It requires the `.stop` suffix because of a bug documented [here](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10373)

**Script section**

```js
export default {
  // ...
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "Name", value: "name" },
        { text: "Monitor", value: "monitor" },
        { text: "Manage", value: "manage" }
      ],
      records: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Item 1",
          monitor: true,
          manage: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Item 2",
          monitor: false,
          manage: true
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Item 3",
          monitor: false,
          manage: false
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    setSwitchesForItem(itemId, attributeName, attributeValue) {
      const record = this.records.find(r => r.id === itemId);
      // In case the new value is true, we need to make sure the other one is set to false
      if (attributeValue) {
        record[attributeName === "monitor" ? "manage" : "monitor"] = false;
      }
      record[attributeName] = attributeValue;
    }
  }
}
```

Link to the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/chamboug/pen/MWKOywJ?editors=1010).